# How do I have two materials on the same object with different properties

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I would like to make something like this: [image: Gold leaf on rock]

How do I make the leaf with its properties as an overlay over the rock? My goal is to use this on a complex object later on, preferably movable. I can make the gold leaf and the rock, but I don't know how to make the leaf as an overlay that I can just move around - and the leaf and the rock to have separate properties/materials.

Can I have two shaders and somehow limit the visibility on one of them using the alpha property, without mixing the color where they overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pepare a material that is a mix between your stone base texture and your gold texture, plug an *Image Texture* in the factor of the *Mix Shader*, create a new image that is black:

[image]

Switch to *Texture Paint* mode and paint in white to reveal the gold shader:

[image]